# string list as a parameter in url in django

Tags: django, url, django-rest-framework, path

i am working in a search view which take two inputs as a filter :

1. search word

2.cities (multi select)

i did it using serializer and it worked but paggination does not work because it was a post method , so i'm trying to take these inputs from url parameters , i tried this pattern :

```
    path(r"search/<str:search>/(?P<city>\w*)/",
            SearchView.as_view({"get": "search"}), name="search"),
```

but when i browse : http://127.0.0.1:8000/company/search/taxi/montrial/
it return Not Found: /company/search/
so how to pass the paramteres or is there another way to use  paggination with post method

Comment: Wouldn't be it better to use `GET` attributes? Like `?city=Montrial`? Also, isn't it Montreal? :)

Comment: but how the url will be to use these get attributes ? or it's not related to url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it using the serializer method, inherit from viewsets.GenericViewsets which has pagingation methods

```
class SearchView(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsDriver]
    queryset = CompanyProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SearchSerializer

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=False)
    def search(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = SearchSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        page = self.paginate_queryset(serializer.data["companies"])
        if page is not None:
            # used CompanyProfileSerializer to serialize the companies query
            serializer = CompanyProfileSerializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use pagination with get request or in case you should do it with post

```
class CustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
def get_paginated_response(self, data):
    return Response({
        'links': {
            'next': self.get_next_link(), #you can read page number from url and put it here
            'previous': self.get_previous_link()
        },
        'count': self.page.paginator.count,
        'results': data
    })
```

to read data from url you can use **request.query_params**

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

Comment: this will indicate which paginate class to use but the problem was i don't know how to return a paginated response in a custom api

Comment: If I understood you correctly, make a specific paginated class and add it like it for custom Api class will work

Comment: class BillingRecordsView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Billing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BillingRecordsSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination # here you can specific it

and the response will be as normal response plus more data to control in page(data)

Comment: but specifying the pagination class does not specify page processing , i already specified a general pagination class in settings and that does not work because there is no code handle the pagination processing in my view , i looked at the mixins.ListModelMixin and i found how they handle the pagination,  i wrote the sloution in an answer